# index.html under /var/www/html not opening

Tags: apache, amazon-ec2, virtualhost

I just provisioned an AWS EC2 Linux Server and performed the following tasks.
1) Installed Tomcat.
2) Installed MySQL DB Server.
3) Apache HTTP Server.
4) Started the Apache HTTPD Server.
5) Changed the httpd.conf to have to have 
   ServerName www.**mywebsitename**.com:80 --[mywebsitename is placeholder here]
6) etc/hosts file modified to have 127.0.0.1 www.**mywebsitename**.com
7) "/var/www/html" has already "Hello World" content in index.html file.
8) Other entries in httpd.conf file
    DocumentRoot "/var/www/html" &
    DirectoryIndex index.html index.html.var

CONCERN:
When I type the IP address from external computer, it should display index.html page as UI. But this is not happening. This is the problem. I tried the same with my website address also. In both the cases(IP and website) it takes lot of time and then displays "This page can’t be displayed" etc.

Please help. 
Apologize if I am missing something.

Thanks!

Comment: Fixed. The port #80 was not opened.

Answer (score 2):

This was taken care. Problem was the port 80 which was not open as part of inbound security rules. As soon as it got opened page got opened.